# Router.Navigate doesn't work after updating Router 3.0.1 to 3.4.1

Tags: angular, typescript

```
const myRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "error", component: ErrorComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "", component: HomeComponent }
];
```

I have the above routes. By default it initiates the HomeComponent and in the constructor, it has a condition to check for errors which leads to the ErrorComponent.

```
this.router.navigate(["/error"]);
```

However, after updating the router, in addition to other angular libraries and dependencies. This no longer works. The URL routes to the error path, but the component isn't initiated. I have a break point in the constructor, but it doesn't get hit. There is also no error in the console. I tried to make the ErrorComponent the default page, just to check if something went wrong in the component itself, but it actually loads, just not when a path is associated with the component.

Not sure if it is relevant, but I haven't done any lazy loading, so all of the components get constructed at the beginning.

I looked at the documentation to see if there are any differences. I also tried changing the call to:

```
this.router.navigate(["error"], { relativeTo: this.route }); 
//where "route" is ActivatedRoute
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the path to the the routes defined under

```
RouterModule.forChild()
```

Not sure why it worked before under

```
 RouterModule.forRoot()
```